# Why does 802.15.4 increase the slot duration instead of increasing the number of slots?

Tags: symbol-timing

The active portion of the superframe duration is given by: $\text{SD} = \text{aBaseSuperFrameDuration} \cdot 2^{\text{SO}}$. With $\text{aBaseSuperFrameDuration}={960}{\text{symbols}}$. The active portion of the superframe duration is divided into 16 equal slots. So we have $T_{\text{slot}} = \frac{\text{SD}}{16}$ symbols for each slot.

We can increase the superframe order ($\text{SO}$) from 0 to 15. Increasing the slot size is decreasing the power savings but increasing the transmission time. Initially, I thought that increasing the superframe order would allow us to support more devices. However, we have slotted CSMA/CA. So in the end, at **max** 16 station can transmit in a beacon interval. So these "at max 16 station" can just send longer messages with a longer active period. I would have designed 802.15.4 with equal slot duration and just increasing the number of slots. More slots, more transmission opportunities. I don't understand why 802.15.4 was designed with a constant number of slots. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but generally:

More slots would need a proportional amount of synchronization overhead.

A frame twice as long thus allows for more data than two original-length frames.

Comment: Yes, very logical.